# Perl script which operates on an input file

Tags: scripting, perl

I am trying to write a script which takes a file as input, reads each line of that file, performs a find based on the value of the file contents, and writes the output to a different file. What I have so far does not do anything.

I'm not concerned about making the code look pretty or adhering to good programming rules right now. The script will be used once to traverse several hundred lines of input file and never used again.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
$in_file = $ARGV[1];
$out_file = '<my_output>.out';

open(IN, "< $in_file");

while(<IN>)
{
    print "input  $in_file \n";
 find /<directory> -type f -name $_ -print >> $out_file;
 }
```

Comment: Are you saying that you have a file "thelist" with a list of filenames, and for each file in "thelist", you want to run "find"?
If so, then it sounds as though you want to use `xargs`, e.g.:
    xargs -n 1 find [...] < thelist

Comment: So far it looks like this could be done in pure Bash, which will be simpler. Is it important to use Perl?

Comment: You need to use backticks or `system()` to execute external commands. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators and http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

GetOptions( 'dir=s' => \my $Flag_Directory ) or exit 1;

die "Usage: $0 [--dir=d] inputfile outputfile\n" if @ARGV < 2;

$Flag_Directory = '/etc/' if !defined $Flag_Directory;
$Flag_Directory = quotemeta($Flag_Directory);

my $output_file = pop @ARGV;
open my $outfh, '>', $output_file
  or die "$0: could not write '$output_file': $!\n";

while (readline) {
    chomp;
    print "input: '$_'\n";
    my $filename = quotemeta($_);
    print $outfh qx(find $Flag_Directory -type f -name $filename -print);
}
```

Though in Perl it would be more idiomatic to instead use [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) or [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) instead of shelling out.